# Can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python

This is proving to be a rough transition over to python. What is going on here?:

```
f = open( 'myfile', 'a+' )
f.write('test string' + '\n')

key = "pass:hello"
plaintext = subprocess.check_output(['openssl', 'aes-128-cbc', '-d', '-in', test, '-base64', '-pass', key])
print (plaintext)

f.write (plaintext + '\n')
f.close()
```

The output file looks like:

`test string`

and then I get this error:

```
b'decryption successful\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Project.py", line 36, in <module>
    f.write (plaintext + '\n')
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Comment: Decode your plaintext or encode the newline.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`subprocess.check_output()` returns a bytestring.

In Python 3, there's no implicit conversion between unicode (`str`) objects and `bytes` objects. If you know the encoding of the output, you can `.decode()` it to get a string, or you can turn the `\n` you want to add to `bytes` with `"\n".encode('ascii')`

Answer (score 15):

subprocess.check_output() returns bytes.

so you need to convert '\n' to bytes as well:

```
 f.write (plaintext + b'\n')
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can convert type of `plaintext` to string:

```
f.write(str(plaintext) + '\n')
```

Comment: On [answer] you can find more information on well-formed answers. Your answer can be correct but it is quiet brief.

Answer (score 1):

```
f.write(plaintext)
f.write("\n".encode("utf-8"))
```