# How to resolve that error":TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

i am making a backdoor buy using python 3. Am facing error
**Error**

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

**json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)**

**piece of code cause error**

```
def reliable_receive(self):
    json_data = ""
    while True:
        try:
            json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
            return json.loads(json_data)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string and https://stackoverflow.com/q/21916888/12239523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc for `json.loads` it'll accept either `str` or `bytes` as its argument, but you'll need to pick one or the other; you can't add a `str` and `bytes` together since they represent different types of data.

Since you're receiving a `bytes` object from `recv`, you probably want your `json_data` to also be a `bytes`.  Just declare it as such up front:

```
json_data = b""
```

Alternatively, you could decode the `recv` return value in order to convert it to a `str`; in that case you'll need to know the encoding or certain byte sequences may raise an error.

Comment: yes that works thanks for clearing my concept but now am facing error                              Listener.reliable_receive of <__main__.Listener object at 0x7f1706febd00>>

Answer (score 1):

self.connection.recv(1024) returns bytes so you have to decode it as a string first like this:

```py
self.connection.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
```

(utf8 is the encoding, you may have to change it to ascii (or something else), depending on the encoding of the sent data)

Comment: yes that work but now am getting eror bound method Listener.reliable_receive of <__main__.Listener object at 0x7f1706febd00>>