# Python error: print(data + "\n") TypeError: can't concat str to bytes when trying to send command through network socket

Tags: python, sockets, send

Hello I am trying to send a command from one computer to another through a python socket. I am able to successfully connect to the computer and see the users ip address but when I try to send a command from host machine it gives me this error     client_socket.send(command)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

This is all of my code:

```
import socket
import subprocess, os

print("#####################")
print("# Python Port Maker #")
print("#                   #")
print("#'To Go Boldy Where'#")
print("#  No Other Python  #")
print("#      Has Gone     #")
print("#      By Riley     #")
print("#####################")

host = input("What host would you like to use? ")
port = int(input("What port would you like to use? "))
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
server_socket.bind((host, port))

server_socket.listen(5)  
print("\n[*] Listening on port " +str(port)+ ", waiting for connections.")

client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = server_socket.accept()
print("[*] Client " +client_ip+ " connected.\n")

while True:
try:
    command = input(client_ip+ "> ")
    if(len(command.split()) != 0):
        client_socket.send(b'command')
    else:
        continue
except(EOFError):
        print("ERROR INPUT NOT FOUND. Please type 'help' to get a list of commands.\n")
        continue

if(command == "quit"):
    break

data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print(data + "\n")

client_socket.close()
```

This is the error it gives me:

```
print(data + "\n")
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Any Help? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't concat bytes to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916888/cant-concat-bytes-to-str). All I did was to search for the error message, which gives me plenty of similar questions. Also, you should have extracted a [mcve]. Doing so, you would have found that this is not tied to the use of sockets. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but you could try something like:

```
client_socket.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
```

So that your command is sent as bytes instead of as a string.

Comment: When I tried that I got    TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: And then also the name utf is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Here `client_socket` is a [socket object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) and takes [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) as argument.

Since `command` is a string try `client_socket.send(b'command')` to use it as bytes object.

EDIT

`client_socket.recv(1024)` returns `bytes` object so `data` variable is bytes object.

Try `print(data)` or convert bytes object string `print(data.decode('utf-8') + '\n')`.

utf-8 is used here because it is a very common encoding, but you need to use the encoding your data is actually in.

If it doesn't work try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/14337549).

Comment: Now I am getting a different error on my code:     print(data + "\n")
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: This is also the 'data' var data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(data + "\n")

Comment: @Riley check the edited answer.

Comment: I think I need to encode bytes and decode them as str or encode str and decode them as bytes