# python 3: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, typeerror

I'm updating my code from python 2 and I'm getting an error that worked in that version before. I'm so lost, please help.

I'm getting an error here at except function:

```
for c in text:
  try:
      if isEncrypt:
          i = tp_alphabet.index(c)
          ret += tc_alphabet[i]
       else:
          i = tc_alphabet.index(c)
          ret += tp_alphabet[i]
   except ValueError as e:
          wrchar = c.encode('utf-8')
          raise Exception("Can't find char '" + wrchar + "' of text in alphabet!")
```

when I run this:

```
dec = machine.decrypt(plaintext)
print(dec)
```

This is the error:

```
File "python3.py", line 133, in __encDec
    raise Exception("Can't find char '" + wrchar + "' of text in alphabet!")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Comment: [Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916888/cant-concat-bytes-to-str)

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `wrchar = c.encode('utf-8')` does? Why is this line in your code?

Comment: Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ for background.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I don't think that is a good selection of duplicate. It sort of explains the problem; but in that case it was appropriate to do a conversion, while in this case it is more appropriate to *remove* an unnecessary conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm updating my code from python 2

In 2.x, and without using any `__future__` declarations, the type `str` is the same as `bytes`, and Unicode text (also known as **text**) is stored in `unicode` objects.

Presumably, `text` (and therefore also `c`) was of type `unicode` in the 2.x version of the code, while ordinary string literals (such as `"Can't find char '"`) are `str` (i.e., `bytes`) objects. So a conversion was needed: encoding the Unicode data into bytes, to be concatenated together - i.e., the line of code `wrchar = c.encode('utf-8')`.

In 3.x, strings work properly. `str` is the text type, storing Unicode code points (**not** the same as characters, BTW), and is **not** an alias for `bytes`. There is no `unicode` any more, but if there were, it would be the same as `str`.

Therefore, it is now not only unnecessary, but a bug to do this encoding step. So what you need to do is remove that, and insert `c` into the output string directly.

While we're modernizing, let's assemble the string in a modern way.

```
except ValueError as e:
    raise Exception(f"Can't find char '{c}' of text in alphabet!")
```

Comment: Good explanation. There is some more detail in the [official migration guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data).