# Set simple Markdown script in python

Tags: python, markdown

I am trying to use Markdown with python, but I am having trouble:

```
import markdown

layers = [1,2,3]
lr = 2
dir = 'result'

with open('readme.md', 'a+') as f:
    f.write('## Layer sizes')
    for layer in layers:
        f.write('* {}'.format(layer))
    f.write('## Learning rate is {}'.format(lr))
    f.write('## Init')
    f.write('Add note about init')
    markdown.markdownFromFile(input=f, output=dir+'/out.html')
```

I get the error `can't concat str to bytes` which is a common question, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916888/cant-concat-bytes-to-str). I tried different arrangement of changing to bytes or back to string, but I still can't get it to work; instead I just get a slightly different error, but the whole theme is str and byte compatibility. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You should add which line exactly causes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems like, `markdown` package works only on **Binary files** instead of Text files, so encode the individual strings that you're writing to the `readme.md` file and pass in file pointers as the input and output instead of just the name of the file.

```py
import markdown as md

layers = [1,2,3]
lr = 2
dir = 'result'

with open('readme.md', 'ab+') as f:
    f.write('## Layer sizes\n'.encode())

    for layer in layers:
        f.write(f'* {layer}\n'.encode())

    f.write(f'## Learning rate is {lr}\n'.encode())
    f.write('## Init\n'.encode())
    f.write('Add note about init\n'.encode())

md.markdownFromFile(input=open("readme.md", "rb"), output=open("out.html", "wb"))
```